# How to use sql Query inside MVEL Script?

Tags: java, sql, mvel

Using my MVEL script I need query some db .So i need to write some mvel expression with sql query .is it possible to use sql query inside mvel script
help me 
thanks in advance?

Comment: Does [this](http://oshyn.com/web-content-management/using-mvel-expression-language-with-opentext-technology) help?

Comment: Yes very much possible, just need to parse the expression, and one should know the main entity class name to create joins using its properties. We have done the same in our project, where we parse the user defined expression, evaluate few parameters using MVEL, and then later fire the full fledged query on DB